# Generating random number with different digits

Tags: function, python-2.7, loops, random, while-loop

So I need to write a program which generates random numbers from 100 to 999, and the tricky part is that the digits in the number **can't** be the same.

For example: `222`, `212` and so on are not allowed.

So far, I have this:

```
import random

a = int (random.randint(1,9)) <-- first digit
b = int (random.randint(0,9)) <-- second digit
c = int (random.randint(0,9)) <-- third digit

if (a != b and a != b and b != c):
    print a,b,c
```

As you can see, I generate all three digits separately. I think it's easier to check if there are same digits in the number.

So, now I want to do a loop that will generate the numbers until the requirements are met (now it either prints blank page or the number). Note that it generates only once and I have to open the program again.

In C++ I did that with the '***while loop***'. And here I don't know how to do it.

And one more question. How can I code the number(quantity) of random numbers I want to generate? 
To be more specific:
I want to generate 4 random numbers. How should I code it?

**P.S.**
*Thank you all for your answers and suggestions, I am really keen on learning new techniques and codes.*

Comment: So you're not really generating random numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop until it's ok you can also use while in Python:

```
from random import randint

a = randint(1, 9)
b = randint(0, 9)
c = randint(0, 9)
while not (a!=b and b!=c and c!=a):
    a = randint(1, 9)
    b = randint(0, 9)
    c = randint(0, 9)
```

You can also put it in a function:

```
def generate_number():
    a = randint(1, 9)
    b = randint(0, 9)
    c = randint(0, 9)
    while not (a!=b and b!=c and c!=a):
        a = randint(1, 9)
        b = randint(0, 9)
        c = randint(0, 9)
    return (a, b, c)
```

And if you want `n` such numbers (they are not actually numbers since `(a, b, c)` is a tuple of 3 `int` values), you can call it `n` times:

```
for i in range(n):
    print(generate_number())
```

If you prefer [formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) the values, you can also do:

```
for i in range(n):
    print('%d %d %d'%generate_number()) # old style formatting
    print('{} {} {}'.format(*generate_number())) # new style
```

Finally, you can use get `n` from the command line:

```
import sys
n = sys.argv[1]
```

Or you can ask it directly:

```
n = int(input("Please enter some number: ")) # in python2.x you'd use raw_input instead of input
```

You'll get an exception if the value cannot be converted; you can catch the exception and loop as for the generation of numbers.

Putting it all together with the typical `main` construct:

```
from random import randint
import sys

def generate_number():
    a = randint(1, 9)
    b = randint(0, 9)
    c = randint(0, 9)
    while not (a!=b and b!=c and c!=a):
        a = randint(1, 9)
        b = randint(0, 9)
        c = randint(0, 9)
    return (a, b, c)

def main():
    n = sys.argv[1]
    for i in range(n):
        print('{} {} {}'.format(*generate_number()))

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks both of you ^^ You really helped me. I don't know, maybe I'm very optimistic, but I was really close (yet so far) to the code Francis Colas wrote....Thank you again :)

I just don't like one thing, that It prints the number like this [1,0,9] instead of this 1 0 9 (yes, I know they are separate digits) , but maybe it's possible for a better outcome? x_X

Besides, I don't know why, but..this 'for loop' works weird here (comparing with c++) , I think I might be doing something wrong, because I am trying to do that this 'n' would be as an input from keyboard...

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to use `random.sample` to sample from the distribution [0,9] without replacement, rejecting any samples which select `0` first:

```
import random

def pick_number():
    a = 0
    while a == 0:
        a, b, c = random.sample(range(10), 3)
    return 100*a + 10*b + c
```

Further explanation: `range(10)` (in Python 2) generates the list `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`, and `random.sample` picks 3 elements from it without replacement. The `while` loop repeats until the first element, `a` is not zero, so when it exits you have the three digits of a number that meets the requirements. You can turn this into a single integer by multiplying the first by 100, the second by 10 and then adding all three.

Comment: Explaining a bit further what exactly your code does might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of generating 3 random numbers create a list of numbers 0-9 then call `random.shuffle` on it. You then just pull out as many digits as you need from the shuffled list and no digit will be repeated

```
import random

def generate_number():
    numbers = range(10) # Generates a list 0-9
    random.shuffle(numbers) # Shuffle the list

    return (numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2]) #take the first 3 items
```

(This answer is pretty much the same as [xnx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29183916/80274) execpt it uses the method `shuffle` which can be used in version prior to 2.3 and it does not loop waiting for a non 0 first digit.)

Answer (score 0):

On top of @xnx answer, some background: this is called Fisher-Yates (or F-Y-Knuth) shuffle, and it is similar to randomly picking lottery tickets, using ticket only once. O(n) complexity, more to read here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle