# I'm trying to generate a random distinct 3 or 4 digit number

Tags: java, random

I'm trying to generate a random distinct 3 or 4 digit number in Java, without using loops, arrays, or methods( except the in built math random method for generating random numbers) , just the basic stuff like if statements.

I tried

(int)(Math.random()*9899+100);

But it's only returning 4 digit indistinct numbers. 
By distinct I mean, no number should repeat itself. Numbers like 232, 7277, 889, 191 aren't allowed. But numbers like 1234, 3456, 8976, 435 are distinct and allowed

Comment: What does "distinct" mean? That the digits are all different?

Comment: "without using loops, arrays, or methods" this is quite an ask.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating random number with different digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29183789/generating-random-number-with-different-digits)

Comment: *"without using loops, arrays, or methods"* - `random()` is a method.  Aside from that, what do you mean by "distinct" or "indistinct" in this context?  Can you provide a sample output from this and describe in what way it's different from what you expect?

Comment: why i got downvotes?

Comment: @MuntasirAonik for providing an answer that meets neither the distinct nor "3 or 4 digit" requirements.

Comment: "without using methods" - your code snippet already uses one, `Math.random()`. Is this allowed or not? Could you please go into detail about the exact restrictions of your task? Voting to close because unclear.

Comment: I've edited the question for more clarity

Comment: *without using loops, arrays, or methods( except the in built math random method for generating random numbers) , just the basic stuff like if statements* We need to talk about the basic stuff. Loops, arrays **and** methods. Those are **not** more complex than `if` statements. In fact, they are still "procedural"; Java is an "Object Oriented" language. The fundamental problem you will face, you need to store the numbers you have already generated somewhere; or you can't guarantee they won't repeat. There are multiple ways to achieve what you want, but you *started* by tieing your hands.

Comment: Here's what you do: initialize an array 'nums` with every 3- or 4-digit number that meets your criteria of an "allowed" number.  Don't want to use a loop?  No problem: just write 'em out; heck, there aren't even ten thousand such numbers... Like this:`int[] arr = {/* not 100 or 101*/ 102, 103, 104, ... 231, /* not 232 or 233 */ 234, ... ,9875, 9876};`  To pick one at random, use `arr[Math.random() * nums.length]`.

Comment: @KevinAnderson *or*, fill a `List` with sequentially 101 to 9999. Use [`Collections.shuffle(List)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-). Take `n` elements from `List`. `List<Integer> al = IntStream.rangeClosed(101, 9999).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());` then `Collections.shuffle(al);` and then `al.stream().limit(n).forEach(System.out::println);` - four lines of code. Including defining and initializing `n`. No arrays. A few methods though. And I guess the `forEach` is a loop. Oh well.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch "without a loop" is often, IMHO, code for "using [Java8] streams".  Yes, you didn't write an explicit `for` or `while` statement, but it's still a loop. And that's not a bad thing.  It's just bloody _fundamentals_--- you know, what they used to teach back in _my_ day.  What these kids today are learning, who knows?

Comment: @KevinAnderson The `IntStream.rangeClosed` is probably a loop too. They're everywhere! Reminds me of [Real Programmers](https://xkcd.com/378/).

Answer (score 1):

The following is not going to generate the numbers fairly but any 4 digit number can be generated, 3 digit numbers are not going to have 0 in them.

```
// first digit between 0 and 9, if it's 0 we will have a 3 digit number
int first = (int)(Math.random() * 10);  

int second = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
// if it's the same as the first add one to it, use modulo to wrap around
if (first == second)
    second = (second + 1) % 10;

// the same as with second digit just with more checks
int third = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
if (third == first || third == second)
    third = (third + 1) % 10;
// if it's still the same, add one once more, after doing it a second time new digit is guaranteed 
if (third == first || third == second)
    third = (third + 1) % 10;

// the same as with second digit just with more checks
int fourth = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
if (fourth == first || fourth == second || fourth == third)
    fourth = (fourth + 1) % 10;
if (fourth == first || fourth == second || fourth == third)
    fourth = (fourth + 1) % 10;
if (fourth == first || fourth == second || fourth == third)
    fourth = (fourth + 1) % 10;

System.out.println(1000 * first + 100 * second + 10 * third + fourth);
```

You can add the new digit to itself instead of adding one to have a more uniform distribution, it requires handling of some corner cases.